# How to reference classes from a Maven project in Eclipse 2019-09?

Tags: java, eclipse

Using Eclipse 2019-09, my goal is to use OpenPDF library, but first, I need to be able to debug its code a bit when calling from my test project.
I have created a workspace where I have created a simple java program that would open a PDF.

I have cloned the OpenPDF repo, and I have added the projects to Eclipse. They are Maven projects.
Now, I need to setup the relation between the projects, in order to use OpenPDF code.

I've read here that I should add openpdf project to the Projects in Java Build Path of my test project, but that is not clear. If I add the openpdf project to the Classpath entry there, it's not compiling because it does not find the openpdf project classes.

So, what is the right setup? (I am not asking how to refer a library through Maven and I don't intend to build a signed Maven library).

Comment: just add a dependency in your  pom.xml and build your project.

Comment: I don't make my test project as Maven. So I have no pom.xml. Also, I would disable Maven for the openpdf project.

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file in the default package? If yes, delete it (or move everything from the _Classpath_ to the _Modulepath_ and in `module-info.java` add `requires ...;` statements for each dependency).

Comment: @Mike so you intend to use maven without using maven?

Comment: @howlger that's assuming that those dependencies are modular, right?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, having a `module-info.java` file in the default package enables [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). JPMS is only one possibility/implementation of modularity and in comparison to OSGi limited (if you do not use `jlink`, using JPMS is usually not worth the effort).

Comment: @howlger he can add a module-info in his project, but that doesn't automatically make the library he wants to use modular, which, if I understand it correctly (never used it, so might be wrong) has to be the case.

Comment: @Stultuske Having a `module-info.java` file in the default package enables JPMS and in JPMS dependencies on the classpath (instead of on the modulepath) cannot be accessed.

Comment: I don't intend to use Maven at all, just to get a library out the maven project by adding the java nature and disabling the Maven nature.

Comment: I've added a module to both projects, then, at runtime, it does not find the dependency module (openpdf). Can't figure out if Eclipse should be able to set that or not.

Comment: Both projects? Do you have a `module-info.java` file in the default package, yes or no? Please show your code, the project structure and the Java Build Path.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I've been detoured. I think Eclipse is hard to manage without Maven, so I'll work with Maven, by referring it locally for debug purposes.

Comment: @mike Maven projects are best opened as Maven projects and Gradle projects are best opened as Gradle projects. Plain Java project can be easily managed in Eclipse, but converting a Maven or a Gradle project is a time-consuming process and in most cases makes no sense.

Comment: @howlger, right. Maven is stellar. Don't know Gradle. But even after conversion, adding manually params to Eclipse project is not great.